# NGXS state returns object instead of actual data

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I'm new to NGXS. So just to test, i've tried the simple setup on simple test app where you import the state in the app component using the `forRoot` and everything works fine.

Now I have a slightly bigger app and i've found the `forFeature` function for feature states. So in my module I have the following code:

```
imports: [...,
NgxsModule.forFeature([MyFeatureState]),
...]
```

Then I lazy load my modules in the routing module of each feature like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'my-feature', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'my-feature', loadChildren: './my-feature/my-feature.module#MyFeatureModule'},
    ]
}
];
```

Then here's my state class:

```
export interface MyFeatureStateModel {
  myFeatures: MyFeature[]
}

@State<MyFeatureStateModel>({
  name: 'myFeatures',
  defaults: {
    myFeatures: []
}
})
@Injectable()
export class MyFeatureState {
   constructor(private myFeatureService: MyFeatureService) {}

   @Select()
   static getAll(state: MyFeatureStateModel) {
      return state.myFeatures;
   }
 }
```

I have the following select on my display component:

```
@Select(MyFeatureState.getAll) myFeature$: Observable<any>;
```

There's a problem when selecting the data on the state. You'll notice i've used any for now as I don't know what's really being returned here, but when I subscribe to `myFeature$` I can see the data and it's also being returned, but instead of returning just the data itself, it returns like this:

```
{myFeature: Array[]} // the array is the actual data
```

Also when I print to console the snapshot of the state I get the following:

```
{
  myFeature:
     myFeature: []
}
```

So what happens is when I subscribe I have an extra step like this:

```
this.myFeature$.subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.myFeature = data.myFeature;
  // previously I only have to do this.myFeature = data
});
```

This is all fine except that previously when I tried the `forRoot` I didn't have to do this.

Also, additional problem when I use the `forFeature` the state cannot automatically detect that the store already has data so it keeps on querying the backend even though there's already data in the store. I had to add an if statement which I think is not ideal. Also before when I use the `forRoot` it can automatically detect so the app only query the backend once and only on page load.

Any idea why these are happening?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.myFeature$.subscribe(({data}) => {
  this.myFeature = data.myFeature;
});
```